# 'If' statement doesn't return what it's meant to

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, not-operator

Am I just being blind or does this `if` statement genuinely not do what it's meant to?

```
Dim textSample as String = "F"
If Not textSample = "D" Or Not textSample = "E" Or Not textSample = "F" Then
    MessageBox.Show("False")
End If
```

This displays the message box even though textSample is one of the letters. In my eyes that `if` statement should see that textSample is one of those letters and skip it, whereas if it was Z it would "Not" be equal to any of those and would therefore show the message box.

Why does it step into the `if` statement?

Comment: To help yourself understand better, you might want to work out [why Robert's answer and mine are actually the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cond1 Or cond2 Or ... Or condn` is true if and only if at least one of the given conditions are true. In your case it is always the case that at least one of the conditions is true (in fact at least two of the conditions will be true in each case). For example if `textSample` is `"D"` then the condition `Not textSample = "E"` and the condition `Not textSample = "F"` will be true. So the whole condition will be true.

Long story short: Use And instead of Or.

Answer (score 3):

It is acting normally.  `True Or True Or False = True`

I believe what you want is

```
Dim tBadLetters() As String = {"D", "E", "F"}

If Not tBadLetters.COntains(txtSample)
  MsgBox("blah")
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no value of textSample for which your if condition could possibly be false. I think you want this instead:

```
If Not (textSample = "D" Or textSample = "E" Or textSample = "F") Then 
   MessageBox.Show("False")
```

If you don't see the difference, examine [the truth tables for both versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd98A.png).

Answer (score 2):

It's because your using an OR clause, you need to use AND.  Basically your saying if the textSample is not D then show your message box.

Change it to:

```
Dim textSample as String = "F"
If Not textSample = "D" AND Not textSample = "E" AND Not textSample = "F" Then
   MessageBox.Show("False")
End If
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

The message will always show. Here is why. In your example let us say textSample = "F". Then

```
if Not F equals D  Or  Not F equals E  or Not F equals F
```

So let us summarize:

```
if (F not equals D ) or ( F not equals E ) or ( F not equals F)
```

...
    if ( true ) or (true) or (false)

So your condition is true no matter what textSample is... (except if your textSample could be at the same be equals to "D" and equals to "E" and equals to "F").

I think you want to change the "or" to "and".

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write it like so:

```
Dim textSample As String = "F"

If textSample <> "D" AndAlso textSample <> "E" AndAlso textSample <> "F" Then
   MessageBox.Show("False")
End If
```

If you, like me, like to use the chainability of .NET, I also wrote for myself several String Extensions for cases like this:

```
Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNullOrBlank(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return s Is Nothing OrElse s.Trim.Length.Equals(0)
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNotNullOrBlank(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Return s IsNot Nothing AndAlso s.Trim.Length > 0
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsEqualToAny(ByVal s As String, ByVal ParamArray values As String()) As Boolean
        If s.IsNotNullOrBlank AndAlso values.Length > 0 Then
            For Each value As String In values
                If s = value Then Return True
            Next
        End If

        Return False
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsNotEqualToAny(ByVal s As String, ByVal ParamArray values As String()) As Boolean
        If s.IsNotNullOrBlank AndAlso values.Length > 0 Then
            For Each value As String In values
                If s = value Then Return False
            Next
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

To where I could then write your If statement like so:

```
Dim textSample As String = "F"

If textSample.IsNotEqualToAny("D", "E", "F") Then
   MessageBox.Show("False")
End If
```